# Embedding material icons charcters in regular text in CodenameOne

Tags: codenameone

Is there a way to inject a material icon character inside a regular text paragraph?

So I need something like this: "Some text"+material icon character here+" some more text". And I want this to flow normally, without extra lines.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that there are several approaches according to the level of generalization of this problem. For example, a complex solution could be an extension of the `RichTextView` class to support this feature (http://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-rich-view-revisited.html).

However, a basic approach could be to have two or three `Label`s inside a `Container` with a `FlowLayout` layout. For example, the following code:

```
    Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());

    Container textWithMaterialIconInside = new Container(new FlowLayout(Component.LEFT));
    textWithMaterialIconInside.add(new Label("Some text", "Label"));
    textWithMaterialIconInside.add(new Label(FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_BACKUP, UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Label"))));
    textWithMaterialIconInside.add(new Label("and other text", "Label"));

    hi.add(textWithMaterialIconInside);
    hi.show();
```

generates this content:

[image]

Comment: The FlowLayout trick only works with short text. For longer texts, that require SpanLabel, won't work. What I did is just create a Label for each word and throw them all in a FlowLayout.

Comment: What you did is exactly the same method used in the RichTextView class (as mentioned above), that allows to use simple tags to format the text (actually it splits the text in `Labels` inside a `FlowLayout`). Another way is the use of a `BrowserComponent` to show html content: the choice depends by the complexity of your use case.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but didn't see any support for images, so I decided to just roll my own utility. I'm gonna accept your answer anyway since it provided me with the hint I needed. Thanks.